# What is the best way to convert PDF? Is it server side or client side?

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, webserver, client

I use PHP for server side and Objective C for client side. I have an iPhone application with an table view, which need to be convert to PDF.

What would you suggest, the server side or the client side?

Examples is always good.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely create the PDF files on your client device:

[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should consider how many clients will use your app at the same time on server side, and the the time to transfer the data.
I suggest to convert to pdf on the client side if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer the data to PHP and have it generate your tables using html2pdf.
It has css support so I recommend it.